# In progress XML parser (xml writer class)

Tags: c++, xml

I was wondering if someone wouldn't mind reviewing this XML writer code that I've been working on. It should be fully functional, and includes an example of how to use it.

### ConsoleApplication1.cpp

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application. 
// 
 
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "XMLReader.h" 
#include "XMLWriter.h" 
#include "XMLErr.h" 
#include <Windows.h> 
 
int main() 
{ 
    XMLWriter doc("test.xml"); 
    doc.CreateDecl("1.0", "utf-8", "true"); 
    doc.CreateRootNode("XML", "id", "test"); 
    XMLNode* childNode = new XMLNode("ACHIEVEMENT"); 
    doc.InsertNode(childNode); 
    doc.InsertAttribute(childNode, "TestAttr", "test"); 
 
    XMLNode* newNode = new XMLNode("TEST", "testinnertext"); 
    childNode->AddChildNode(newNode); 
 
    XMLAttribute* attr = new XMLAttribute("test", "0"); 
    newNode->AddAttribute(attr); 
 
    doc.WriteDoc(); 
    doc.Close(); 
}
```

#### XMLWriter.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "XMLWriter.h" 
 
XMLWriter::XMLWriter(const char* fileName) 
{ 
    file = std::ofstream(fileName); 
} 
 
XMLWriter::~XMLWriter() 
{ 
 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::Close() 
{ 
    if (file.is_open()) 
        file.close(); 
 
    rootNode->Close(); 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::Save() 
{ 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::CreateDecl(const char* version, const char* encoding, bool standalone) 
{ 
    file << "<?xml version=" << "\"" << version << "\" "; 
    if (encoding != nullptr) 
        file << "encoding=" << "\"" << encoding << "\" "; 
    if (standalone != false) 
        file << "standalone=" << "\"" << "true" << "\""; 
 
    file << "?>" << "\n"; 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::CreateRootNode(const char* rootName, const char* attrName, const char* attrValue) 
{ 
    rootNode = new XMLNode(); 
 
    rootNode->SetName(rootName); 
    if (attrName != nullptr && attrValue != nullptr) 
    { 
        XMLAttribute* attribute = new XMLAttribute(attrName,attrValue); 
        attribute->SetName(attrName); 
        attribute->SetValue(attrValue); 
        rootNode->AddAttribute(attribute); 
 
        //file << "<" << rootName << " " << attrName << "=" << "\"" << attrValue << "\"" << ">" << "\n"; 
 
    } 
    else { 
        //file << "<" << rootName << ">"; //<< "\n" << "</" << rootName << ">"; 
    } 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::InsertNode(XMLNode* child) 
{ 
    rootNode->AddChildNode(child); 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::InsertNode(const char* nodeName, const char* nodeValue) 
{ 
    XMLNode* node = new XMLNode(nodeName, nodeValue); 
 
    rootNode->AddChildNode(node); 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::InsertAttribute(XMLNode* target, const char* attrName, const char* attrValue) 
{ 
    target->AddAttribute(attrName, attrValue); 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::WriteDoc() 
{ 
    //TODO: get this gross ass shit functional 
    file << "<" << rootNode->GetName(); 
    for (auto it : rootNode->GetAttributes()) 
    { 
        file << " " << it->GetName() << "=" <<  "\"" << it->GetValue() << "\""; 
    } 
    file << ">"; 
 
    WriteNodesRecursively(rootNode); 
 
    file << "</" << rootNode->GetName() << ">"; 
} 
 
void XMLWriter::WriteNodesRecursively(XMLNode* currNode) 
{ 
    for (auto itor : currNode->GetChildNodes()) 
    { 
        file << "\n"; 
 
        file << "\t" << "<" << itor->GetName(); 
        for (auto it : itor->GetAttributes()) 
        { 
            file << " " << it->GetName() << "=" << "\"" << it->GetValue() << "\""; 
        } 
 
        if (itor->GetInnerText().length() > 0 && itor->GetChildNodes().size() == 0) 
        { 
            file << ">"; 
            file << itor->GetInnerText(); 
            file << "</" << itor->GetName() << ">" << "\n"; 
        } 
        else if (itor->GetChildNodes().size() > 0) 
        { 
            file << ">"; 
            WriteNodesRecursively(itor); 
            file << "\t" << "</" << itor->GetName() << ">" << "\n"; 
        } 
 
    } 
}
```

#### XMLWriter.h

```
#pragma once 
#include "XMLNode.h" 
#include "XMLAttribute.h" 
 
class XMLWriter 
{ 
private: 
    std::ofstream file; 
    XMLNode* rootNode; 
public: 
    XMLWriter() = default; 
    XMLWriter(const char* fileName); 
    ~XMLWriter(); 
    void Close(); 
    void Save(); 
    void WriteDoc(); 
    void WriteNodesRecursively(XMLNode* node); 
public: 
 
    XMLNode * GetRootNode() { return rootNode; } 
    void CreateDecl(const char* version, const char* encoding = 0, bool standalone = 0); 
    void CreateRootNode(const char* nodeName, const char* attrName = 0, const char* attrValue = 0); 
 
    ///All 3 of these are used only to add a childnode to rootnode, otherwise use XMLNodes AddChildNode function 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    void InsertNode(XMLNode* child);                                                                                                                       // 
    void InsertNode(const char* nodeName, const char* attrValue = 0);                                                                                       // 
    void InsertAttribute(XMLNode* target, const char* attrName, const char* attrValue);                                                                       // 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
};
```

#### XMLNode.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "XMLNode.h" 
 
XMLNode::XMLNode(const char* nodeName, const char* nodeInnerText) 
{ 
    name = nodeName; 
    if (nodeInnerText != nullptr) 
        innerText = nodeInnerText; 
} 
 
XMLNode::~XMLNode() 
{ 
 
} 
 
///this is called from XMLReader, delete child node and any child nodes that exists within the instance 
void XMLNode::Close() 
{ 
    for (auto& attribute : attributes) 
        delete attribute; 
 
    for (auto& childNode : childNodes) 
        childNode->Close(); 
 
    attributes.clear(); 
    childNodes.clear(); 
 
    delete this; 
} 
 
void XMLNode::AddAttribute(XMLAttribute* attribute) 
{ 
    attributes.push_back(attribute); 
} 
 
 
void XMLNode::AddAttribute(const char* attrName, const char* attrValue) 
{ 
    XMLAttribute* attr = new XMLAttribute(attrName, attrValue); 
 
    attributes.push_back(attr); 
} 
 
 
void XMLNode::AddChildNode(XMLNode* childNode) 
{ 
    childNodes.push_back(childNode); 
} 
 
XMLAttribute* XMLNode::GetAttribute(const std::string attrName) 
{ 
    for (auto attr : attributes) 
    { 
        if (_stricmp(attr->GetName().c_str(), attrName.c_str()) == 0) 
            return attr; 
    } 
    return nullptr; 
} 
 
XMLNode* XMLNode::GetChildNode(int index) 
{ 
    if (childNodes.empty()) 
        return nullptr; 
 
    return childNodes.at(index); 
} 
 
bool XMLNode::FindChild(XMLNode* node) 
{ 
    for (auto itor : childNodes) 
    { 
        if (itor == node) 
            return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

#### XMLNode.h

```
#pragma once 
#include "XMLAttribute.h" 
 
class XMLNode 
{ 
 
private: 
    std::string name; 
    std::string innerText; 
    std::vector<XMLAttribute*> attributes; 
    std::vector<XMLNode*> childNodes; 
public: 
    XMLNode() = default; 
    XMLNode(const char* nodeName, const char* nodeInnerText = 0); 
    ~XMLNode(); 
 
    void Close(); 
 
    void SetName(const std::string value) { name = value; } 
    const std::string GetName() const { return name; } 
 
    void SetInnerText(const std::string value) { innerText = value; } 
    const std::string GetInnerText() const { return innerText; } 
 
    //give users a choice of either adding a pointer to the function, or creating the pointer in the function, then adding the pointer to the node 
    void AddAttribute(XMLAttribute* attribute); 
    void AddAttribute(const char* attrName, const char* attrValue); 
    void AddChildNode(XMLNode* childNode); 
    // 
 
    XMLAttribute* GetAttribute(const std::string attrName); 
    XMLNode* GetChildNode(int index); 
 
    const std::vector<XMLAttribute*>& GetAttributes() { return attributes; } 
 
    bool FindChild(XMLNode* node); 
 
    const std::vector<XMLNode*>& GetChildNodes() const { return childNodes; } 
};
```

#### XMLAttribute.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "XMLAttribute.h" 
 
XMLAttribute::XMLAttribute(const char* attrName, const char* attrValue) 
{ 
    name = attrName; 
    value = attrValue; 
} 
 
bool XMLAttribute::CheckValue() 
{ 
    for (auto c : value) 
    { 
        if (!isdigit(c)) 
        { 
            throw(std::exception("Error, value is not an integer, or contains a non-numeric value")); 
        } 
    } 
    return true; 
} 
 
const int XMLAttribute::AsInt() 
{ 
    if (!CheckValue()) 
        throw std::exception("Error, attributes value contains a non-numerical character"); 
 
    if (std::stoi(value) > INT_MAX || std::stoi(value) < INT_MIN) 
        throw(std::out_of_range::exception("Error value is outside the range of a signed int")); 
 
    return std::stoi(value); 
} 
 
const unsigned int XMLAttribute::AsUInt() 
{ 
    if (!CheckValue()) 
        throw std::exception("Error, attributes value contains a non-numerical character"); 
 
    if (std::stoul(value) > UINT_MAX || std::stoul(value) < 0) 
        throw(std::out_of_range::exception("Error, value is outside the range of a unsigned int")); 
 
    return std::stoul(value); 
} 
 
const float XMLAttribute::AsFloat() 
{ 
    if (!CheckValue()) 
        throw std::exception("Error, attributes value contains a non-numerical character"); 
 
    if (std::stof(value) > FLT_MAX || std::stof(value) < FLT_MIN) 
        throw(std::out_of_range::exception("Error, value is outside the range of a float")); 
 
    return std::stof(value); 
} 
 
const double XMLAttribute::AsDouble() 
{ 
    if (!CheckValue()) 
        throw std::exception("Error, attributes value contains a non-numerical character"); 
 
    if (std::stof(value) > DBL_MAX || std::stof(value) < DBL_MIN) 
        throw(std::out_of_range::exception("Error, value is outside the range of a float")); 
 
 
    return std::stod(value); 
}
```

#### XMLAttribute.h

```
#pragma once 
 
 
class XMLAttribute 
{ 
private: 
    std::string value; 
    std::string name; 
public: 
    XMLAttribute(const char* attrName, const char* attrValue); 
    void SetValue(const std::string inValue) { value = inValue; } 
    void SetName(const std::string inName) { name = inName; } 
    const std::string GetValue() const { return value; } 
    const std::string GetName() const { return name; } 
 
    ///verifies that the string contains only numeric characters 
    bool CheckValue(); 
 
    ///conversion functions for the attributes value 
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    const int       AsInt();                                 // 
    const unsigned int AsUInt();                                 // 
    const float  AsFloat();                                     // 
    const double AsDouble();                                 // 
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
 
};
```

Comment: When the attributes function _does_ grab attributes that contain whitespace, please update your post. Until then, this post is [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: As long as this parser calls `find_first_of`, it cannot be correct.

Comment: Plus, the code doesn't compile since you didn't post the header file. Some test code would also be nice.

Comment: I'll post some test code tomorrow morning if i have the extra time, but I mostly just wanted a review on how the code itself appears in terms of the quality. Starting to realize how much there is to an xml parser, such a huge task.

Comment: You need to post complete, working code. If you just want a review of part of the code, it still needs to be complete and working for the task you specify.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry,still pretty new to posting on stackexchange and child sites. I updated this, as I focused on the xml writer class first, since it's easier to write an xml than to read an xml.

Comment: Why are there so many blank lines? Is that how you format your code or is it a result of the copy-paste?

Comment: A bit of both honestly, I usually have a little more blank lines than other people, helps me read what I'm doing easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good you have some working code, and good that you've asked for a review.  There are number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Use the required `#include`s

The code uses `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc. which means that it should have

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

and others.  Since you have followed the usual separation the implementation (`.cpp` file) from the interface (the `.h` file), put only those things in the header file that are required to understand the header.  Any implementation details should go into the `.cpp` file if they don't already show up in the header.  As an example, in `XMLAttribute.cpp` we should have:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <climits>
#include <cfloat>
```

while `XMLAttribute.h` should have this:

```
#include <string>
```

### Eliminate unused headers

Nothing from the `<Windows.h>` or `XMLReader.h` or `XMLErr.h` appear to actually have been used within this code, so it would be best to eliminate those from the `ConsoleApplication1` code.  Also, I can't help but think that we can come up with a more descriptive file name for this code.

### Use standard exceptions

In a few places in the code, there are non-standard exceptions like this:

```
throw(std::exception("Error, value is not an integer, or contains a non-numeric value"));
```

There is no `std::exception` constructor that takes a `std::string` or `const char *` as an argument.  Instead, we need to use one of the actual standard types:

```
throw std::domain_error("Error, value is not an integer, or contains a non-numeric value");
```

Also note that `throw` is a keyword and not a function call so the enclosing parentheses are not needed or wanted.

### General portability

This code *could* be made portable if, in addition to the changes in the previous points, you omit the Windows-only include files `#include "stdafx.h"` and `#include <Windows.h>`

### Use exceptions only for exceptional things

There use of exceptions is inconsistent.  For instance, we have this:

```
bool XMLAttribute::CheckValue() const
{
    for (auto c : value)
    {
        if (!isdigit(c))
        {
            throw std::domain_error("Error, value is not an integer, or contains a non-numeric value");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code returns `true` or throws an exception.  That's more than a bit strange, especially because it's only used internally.  I'd suggest instead having it return a `bool` either way and leave it up to the caller to `throw` if needed, since the calling functions are written that way already anyway.

### Use standard library functions

Instead of the code above for `CheckValue`, first, I'd rename it to something that makes it easy to interpret the result such as `containsOnlyDigits`.  That way it's much easier to understand what it's checking and much more obvious to tell what a `true` return value means.

Second, use a standard function for this.  Most convenient here would be to use a C++11 lambda function:

```
bool XMLAttribute::containsOnlyDigits() const {
    return std::all_of(value.begin(), value.end(), 
        [](char c){ return std::isdigit(c); });
}
```

### Don't specify `const` for return values

The `XMLAttribute` member functions `AsInt()`, `AsUInt()`, etc. return a value rather than a pointer or reference, but they don't alter the underlying `XMLAttribute` object.  For that reason, instead of this:

```
const int AsInt();  // returns a const?
```

write this:

```
int AsInt() const;   // does not alter object
```

### Prefer modern initializers for constructors

The constructors could use the more modern initializer style rather than the old style you're currently using.  Instead of this:

```
XMLAttribute::XMLAttribute(const char* attrName, const char* attrValue) 
{ 
    name = attrName; 
    value = attrValue; 
}
```

you could instead write this:

```
XMLAttribute::XMLAttribute(const char* attrName, const char* attrValue) :
    value{attrValue},
    name{attrName}
{}
```

Note also that the member items are initialized in *declaration order* rather than the order they're listed in the constructor, so to avoid any misunderstanding, it's best to write the constructor such that it uses the same order as the declaration.

### Let the compiler create default destructor

The compiler will create a destructor by default which is essentially identical to what you've got, so you can simply omit both the declaraton and implementation from your code.  If you want to make sure the user of the code understands that it's the default-constructed destructor, you can make it very clear by writing this:

```
~XMLNode() = default;
```

### Use C++ idioms

This isn't Java, so having getters and setters for everything (e.g. `GetValue()`, `SetValue()`) is not the norm and is not necessarily a good interface.  For instance, the `XMLNode::getAttribute()` function returns a non-const pointer to its copy of the attribute.  That's a broken design for at least two reasons.  First, it would allow the caller to arbitrarily alter the internals of the class.  Second, if the `XMLNode` object goes out of scope and is destroyed before the returned pointer is dereferenced, you have undefined behavior.  Better would probably be to return a copy.

### Reconsider the interface

There are a number of peculiarities that make this interface less than ideal.  One thing is that the nodes in this scheme are allowed to have idential attribute names.  According to the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#attdecls),

> For interoperability, an XML processor MAY at user option issue a warning when more than one attribute-list declaration is provided for a given element type, or more than one attribute definition is provided for a given attribute, but this is not an error.

Also the `XMLWriter` is tied to a `std::ofstream`.  What if I want to write to a `std::stringstream` instead?  Better would be to have the `Writer` manage serialization of data to any `std::ostream` and allow the user to choose at runtime, independently of how/when the instance data is populated.

### Avoid raw pointers

The code includes this function:

```
bool XMLNode::FindChild(XMLNode* node) 
{ 
    for (auto itor : childNodes) 
    { 
        if (itor == node) 
            return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Is it really intended to be able to use this code while passing `nullptr` into the function?  If so, I'd suggest a check for `nullptr`.  If not, use a `const XMLNode &node` argument and overload an `XMLNode::operator==()` function.

### Understand the XML specification

The `XMLNode::GetAttribute` function inclues these lines

```
if (_stricmp(attr->GetName().c_str(), attrName.c_str()) == 0) 
    return attr;
```

In addition to the already mentioned problem about returning a pointer to internal object data, this seems to imply that XML attribute names are case insensitive.  In fact, they are not, so this appears to be an error in understanding or applying the XML 1.0 specification.  Also `_stricmp` is non-standard code.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions, implementing several of them tonight, and i'll do the others tomorrow. I was wondering though, if getters/setters aren't a good practice for c++, how would you recommend setting/getting the values? just with the member variable?

Comment: Happy to help.  In C++, if any class can get or set member data, just make the members public.

Comment: Will do, thanks. One last question if you don't mind. I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out whether or not I should use a shared_ptr or a unique_ptr. I've read about them a couple times and I'm still unsure which to use. based on this code, what would you recommend? A unique_ptr for the rootnode, and shared_ptrs for the childnodes?